# Issue with numpy for pickled data

Tags: python, numpy, pickle

I have a large amount of data saved as .npy files. Some portion of this data is stored as a list of dictionaries, where each value of the dictionary is a numpy array. I store all of these using `np.save` with `allow_pickle=True`.

Recently, I tried to load the data and received the following error: `UnpicklingError: invalid load key, '\x00'.` I have no idea why this is occurring, though I think it may be because the pickling load file was interrupted. Any ideas on how to solve this? I'm hoping I can at least get some of the data back.

EDIT: The file is here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/x8le962wx724fpq/model.npy?dl=0

Unfortunately, it's almost 100 MB; this is the smallest file I could find and I haven't worked out how to replicate the error yet.

Comment: It would really help if you can post one of the files somewhere that we can download and inspect it.

Comment: @JohnZwinck Added a link!

Comment: I can confirm that your file won't load.  If the data inside is very valuable to you I'm sure you could find a data recovery specialist who could extract as much as possible out of these corrupted files.  Otherwise I think you're out of luck.